# Localization and extension of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Is $\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}[i,\sqrt{2}]=(\mathbb{Z}[i,\sqrt{2}])_{(3)}$ (where by subscript $(3)$ we mean localization at the ideal generated by $3$)?

Do both of these rings contain elements like
$$
\frac{4}{1-\sqrt{2}i}?
$$

Comment: What "both these rings"? In your question question there's only one: the localisation one.

Comment: @DonAntonio He asked two questions. The first was whether those two rings are equal, so later he asked about "both" the rings since he does not know if they are equal yet.

Comment: You're right, @RagibZaman .I just didn't notice that first question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $S$ is a multiplicative subset of a commutative ring $R.$ Intuitively, $S^{-1}R$ is a construction similar to taking a field of fractions, but we only allow things in $S$ to be denominators.

Exercise: An ideal $I$ of $R$ is prime if and only if $R\setminus I$ is a multiplicative subset of $R.$

From that fact, we define the notion of localizing at a prime ideal. We define $R_P=(R\setminus P)^{-1}R.$

So $\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$ is the subfield of the rationals that contains the elements which, when written in lowest terms, are of the form $a/b$ where $a$ is any integer and $b$ is not a multiple of $3.$

Let $B$ be a subring of $A$ and $a\in A.$ Then the ring $B[a]$ is defined to be the intersection of all subrings of $A$ containing $B$ and $a.$ Constructively this is the subset of $A$ with elements of the form $b_0 +b_1 a + b_2 a^2 + b_3 a^3\cdots $ where $b_i\in B$ (only finitely many non-zero). One can check these two definitions are the same by verifying this last set is indeed a subring containing $B$ and $a,$ and that any other such subring contains elements of that form.

Since $\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$ is a subring of the complex numbers, when we adjoin $i$ we see $\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}[i]$ has elements of the form $a_0 + a_1 i + a_2 i^2 \cdots $ but since $i^2=-1$ the elements are just of the form $\alpha + i\beta$ where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Z}_{(3)}.$

Now adjoining $\sqrt{2}$ to that, we see the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}[i,\sqrt{2}]$ are of the form $(\alpha_0+i\beta_0)+(\alpha_1+i\beta_1)\sqrt{2} + (\alpha_2+i\beta_2) \sqrt{2}^2 + \cdots$ and since $\sqrt{2}^2 =2$ we can always write the elements in the form $\alpha+\beta i+\gamma\sqrt{2}+\delta i\sqrt{2}$ where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta \in \mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$ i.e. are rationals which can be written with a denominator not divisible by $3.$ So we have a complete description of what the elements of this ring look like.

For your example, $$ \frac{4}{1-i\sqrt{2} i}=\frac{4}{1-i\sqrt{2} i} \cdot \frac{1+i\sqrt{2}}{1+i\sqrt{2}} = \frac{4+4i\sqrt{2} }{1+2} = \frac{4}{3} + \frac{4}{3} i \sqrt{2}.$$

So the ring on the left hand side does not contain that element, since we can't express $4/3$ as a fraction where the denominator is not a multiple of $3.$

Now consider the ring of the right hand side. $\mathbb{Z}[i,\sqrt{2}]$ consists of elements of the form $a+bi+c\sqrt{2}+di\sqrt{2}$ where $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}.$ The localization will allow denominators that are not divisible by $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i,\sqrt{2}].$ So for example, $\dfrac{1+i}{2+i}= 1+\frac{1}{3}i  $ is in the ring on the right, but it is not in the ring on the left. So the two rings are not equal.

Comment: Your first part still would have to contain the explict assumption/proof that $\,(3)\,$ is a prime ideal in$\,\Bbb Z[i,\sqrt 2]\,$ ...

Comment: Yes I omitted the verification that $3$ is prime in that ring. I only considered the second ring in the last paragraph though so I am confused. Where exactly is the first part that you are referring to?

Comment: Where you talk of $\,\Bbb Z_{(3)}\, is a subfield and etc., where you implicitly assume we have there a multiplicative set...

Comment: @DonAntonio Why do I need $3$ to prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i,\sqrt{2}]$ to localize $\mathbb{Z}$ at $3?$

Comment: Otherwise how can you be sure the set $\,S:=\Bbb Z[i,\sqrt2]-(3)\,$ is closed under multiplication, @Ragib ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes I would need that to localize $\mathbb{Z}[i,\sqrt{2}]$ at 3, but not to localize $\mathbb{Z}$ at 3.

Comment: Well @Ragib, *also* at $\,\Bbb Z\,$ since otherwise, I think, it is not called "localisation"...but I'm not completely sure about this.

Comment: @DonAntonio To be able to localize $\mathbb{Z}$ at 3, we just need to know 3 is prime in $\mathbb{Z}.$ We can talk about $\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$ with just that. We do not need to know that 3 is also prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i,\sqrt{2}]$ to talk about $\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}.$ We would if we wanted to talk about $\mathbb{Z}[i,\sqrt{2}]_{(3)}.$